Lego Koenigsegg Jesko sets 42184 and 42173 are identical save for color. Are there more such pairs?
The Koenigsegg Jesko sets 42184 and 42173 are the exact same builds, as far as I can tell, except for the colors.
42184 is white with green accents, the other one is dark grey with orange/brown accents.
Lego has often re-used various designs as parts of larger sets (with or without the same color-schema). E.g. multiple 1970's Legoland sets used the same police-cars, ambulances and fire-trucks. Some trains and wagons from that era come to mind as well.
But I'm not aware of any other pairs of sets that are completely the same, except for the colors.
Are there more examples to be found?
Please note: Late 60's/early 70's had some re-issues of sets in the 3xx-4xx range with set-numbers in the 6xx-7xx range and updated packaging. I don't mean those. Those were
just the same sets with a different box and set-number.


Do you accept Bionicle sets, where the only differences between sets in some product lines are the coloration and some molding details in the masks or weapons?

@zovits I have no familiarity with Bionicle at all, so I have no idea how significant those differences are. Why don't you put in an answer with an example and let me see how close they are?

Recently there have been quite a few recolors.

Lamborghini Huracán Tecnica Orange (42196) is a recolor of Lamborghini Huracán Tecnica (42161)

Fiat 500 (77942) is a recolor of Fiat 500 (10271)

Mighty Dinosaurs (77940) and Mighty Dinosaurs (77941) are a recolor of Mighty Dinosaurs (31058)

Bugatti Bolide Agile Blue (42162) is a recolor of Bugatti Bolide (42151)

Exotic Pink Parrot (31144) is a recolor of Exotic Parrot (31136) - suggested by user26308


Non-recent examples:

Two sets with same name and ID - Dirt Crusher RC (8369), but different release years and colors: 8369-1 and 8369-2

LEGOLAND California Truck (3442) is a recolor of LEGO Truck (2148)



I had no idea (and I have 10271 myself). The Lambo and Bugatti re-colored sets are sort of in the same series as the Koenigseggs as well.

Most of these look much better in the "new" colors.  Did they choose the original colors because of part availability limitations at the time?

@Tonny recolored Fiat 500 had a limited availability: it had been released in small number of countries as a pilot of some sort. So it was easy to miss it.

No exactly recent, but 4335 is a recolour of 4346

Here is a curious one: 10157 and 10158 are slight recolors of 4511 (light/dark grey became light bluish gray/dark bluish gray)

Also, 75895 is a direct recolor of the Porsche 911 in 75888

The 1996 train station 2150 was a red recolour of the same design from 1991 (4554).
The colour packs for "My Own Train" (3743, 3744 etc.) are the same bricks in five different colours, to be combined with the basic locomotive sets 3740 / 3741.

I think 40522 Valentine Lovebirds is worth mentioning - it's a single set, but composed of two physically identical sculptures with different colours.
